# Prove a number doesn't belong to a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, recurrence-relations

You are given the sequence defined by the following recurrence relation:
$$a_n = \cases{a_0 = 1\\a_1 = 3\\a_{n+1} = 5a_n + a_{n-1}, \forall n \geq 1}$$
You are then asked to prove that $123456789 \notin a_n$.

One thing I noticed is that all the numbers belonging to this sequence are made up by a multiple of $5$ plus another number, that is itself a multiple of $5$ plus another number, going down recursively until the number added is $1$ or $3$. There has to be some other similar property that all numbers in this sequence abide by, which $123456789$ doesn't, that can be used to shown it doesn't belong to the sequence.

Any ideas?

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out to me, and sorry about it. I'll edit my post as soon as I get my hands on my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take it modulo $5$.

You'll get $$a_n\equiv1,3$$ and be healthy!